# Android GPS data is not accurate

Tags: android, gps, maps

I am working in a project that involves getting GPS longitude and latitude , and displaying them on the Map View , However, the result is that the mobile device says I am Nigeria (which is in west Africs), when I am in Egypt (which is in Northeast Africa). Is there a reason my GPS could be so far off?

Comment: We have to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: As Andrei G sais, clearly it's not a bug with the GPS satelites. However, it could be a hardware issue on your Android device. For example some LG devices are well off on their GPS reporting, this is something LG admitted as well. So aside from your code, tell us what device(s) you use for tests as well.

Comment: I am sory I am new in stackoverflow and I donot know how to exceed the limit of the comment , however I will write the most important part of  
//overlays
   'List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
   Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black);
   MapOverlays itemizedoverlay = new MapOverlays(drawable, this);
 
   GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude *1e6), (int)(longitude*1e6));
   OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hint", "Your Current Location");
 
   itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);'

Answer (score 0):

1) ensure you are not using fake locations tools or applications.

2) check your hardware device

to understand if you have broken gps, disable gps and check if, using only wifi or only network provider the location is better (network should have 300 meters precision).